# Is it possible to customize service worker onupdatefound event to have two different types of updates

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, service-worker, workbox

I am using `CRA` with `service-worker` and want to have two kinds of updates for my app simultaneously:

- **Normal update**: service-worker downloads the new version of dashboard in background and  waits until the user closes the application to replace the old version with the new one.
- **Force update**: when there is a critical bug in my app I want to force all users to just use the newest version when the service-worker update finds a forced update.

currently I am using a constant variable inside `service-worker.js` file to set the `lastSupportedVersion` of my app to stop users from using older versions of app.